# Breaking box style by using tcolorbox

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

My code is the following:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at
break*=1pc,title=My Headings,colback=magenta!10,colframe=magenta]
Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For\footnote{Footnote text} some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:
\begin{itemize}
\item they have acquired the knowledge, understanding and means to make positive health decisions

\item they live and work in environments that support them in making health]promoting choices.
\end{itemize}
Others may be influenced by factors that prevent them making good health decisions or limit their ability to easily make choices that will promote better health. For example, they may have poor nutrition due to lack of money, poor availability of nutritious foods in their local area or lack of knowledge of nutrition.

Text 2 Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:
\begin{itemize}
\item they have acquired the knowledge, understanding and means to make positive health decisions

\item they live and work in environments that support them in making health]promoting choices.
\end{itemize}
Others may be influenced by factors that prevent them making good
health decisions or limit their ability to easily make choices that will promote better health. For example, they may have poor nutrition due to lack of money, poor availability of nutritious foods in their local area or lack of knowledge of nutrition. 

Text 3 Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:

Text 4 Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

It is working fine, but for breaking boxes I need an arrow mark as shown below:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I need this Box at the right corner of then end of the first box, I missed to mention it...

Comment: Where should this arrow mark appear? At the bottom of the first box?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, I missed to mention it, now I have updated this to the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A first version placing an overlay for the first and potential middle boxes only and drawing a filled triangle there.

(If the arrow should not appear on the middle boxes of a break sequence, replace `overlay first and middle` by `overlay first`)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,
  breakable,
  pad at break*=1pc,
  title=My Headings,
  colback=magenta!10,
  colframe=magenta,
  overlay first and middle={
    \coordinate (A1) at ($(interior.south east) + (-10pt,5pt)$);
    \coordinate (C1) at ($(interior.south east) + (-6pt,7.5pt)$);
    \draw[fill=tcbcol@frame] (A1) -- +(0,5pt) -- (C1) -- cycle;
  }
  ]
Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For\footnote{Footnote text} some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:
\begin{itemize}
\item they have acquired the knowledge, understanding and means to make positive health decisions

\item they live and work in environments that support them in making health]promoting choices.
\end{itemize}
Others may be influenced by factors that prevent them making good health decisions or limit their ability to easily make choices that will promote better health. For example, they may have poor nutrition due to lack of money, poor availability of nutritious foods in their local area or lack of knowledge of nutrition.

Text 2 Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:
\begin{itemize}
\item they have acquired the knowledge, understanding and means to make positive health decisions

\item they live and work in environments that support them in making health]promoting choices.
\end{itemize}
Others may be influenced by factors that prevent them making good
health decisions or limit their ability to easily make choices that will promote better health. For example, they may have poor nutrition due to lack of money, poor availability of nutritious foods in their local area or lack of knowledge of nutrition. 

Text 3 Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:

Text 4 Health fi fl ffi ffl is \textbf{\textit{the}} result
of a complex interaction of people's personal health behaviours and a range of social, economic, cultural and environmental determinants that exist in the society in which they live. These wider social and cultural forces can shape or limit an individuals decision making, affect power relations, and can determine the amount of control an individual has over his or her actions.

For some people, these factors are conducive to good health; that is:
\blindtext[4]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this what I expected, thanks a lot....

Comment: My apology for this, I have the code by using "framed.sty" package not with "tcolorbox", I have re posted my query as another new question, but really thanks a lot for your great suggestion....

Comment: @MadyYuvi: Oh my .... `tcolorbox` is definitely more powerful than `framed` which hasn't been updated since 2012

Comment: If I am the coder, definitely I should use the tcolorbox only...