# Breaking box style by using framed.sty

Tags: framed, break-box

My code as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,framed,blindtext,amssymb}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{cmyk}{0.02,0.09,0.04,0}%
\begin{shaded}\advance\hsize by -18pt%
\blindtext[8]
\end{shaded}
\end{document}
```

Above said code works fine, but end of first and mid boxes, I need a triangle as shown below:

[image]

I have tried with `\def\FirstFrameCommand{\smash{$\blacktriangle$}\colorbox{shadecolor}}` but the output does not come correctly, is there any possibility to achieve it by using the package `framed.sty`

Comment: Why using `framed` now?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Apology, sorry, I have received the coded file from one of a resource, they used fully framed.sty not tcolorbox, if I change now, it might require more time...

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407729/breaking-box-style-by-using-tcolorbox/407736#407736